# $u''(t)+u(t) = |t|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the Cauchy problem, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \begin{cases}
u''(t) + u(t) = |t|\\
u(0)=1, \quad u'(0) = -1
\end{cases} $$

The solution to the homogeneous equation is $A\cos(t) + B \sin(t)$. Empirically, $|t|$ is "more or less" a particular solution, however it is not differentiable in $0$... What is the fastest way to find a particular solution two times differentiable?

Comment: Solve *two* problems, one for $t\ge 0$, one for $t\le 0$, and verify whether the boundary conditions allow solutions to "match" at $t=0$. Finally, if this is the case, verify that the resulting function is indeed twice differentiable at $t=0$ and satisfies the differential equation at the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can solve the system for $t \ge 0$ and $t \lt 0$.

However, you can use Laplace Transforms to solve the problem, and will arrive at:

- $t \ge 0, u(t) = t - 2 \sin t + \cos t$
- $t \lt 0, u(t) = \cos t - t$

If we check the initial conditions, they match as does the solution with continuity.

A piecewise plot shows:

[image]

Comment: Nice  Amzoti. :-) Good night.

Comment: Nice work $\rightarrow$ TU +1

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle{\xi = {\rm u}' + {\rm iu}
\Longrightarrow
\xi' = {\rm u}'' + {\rm iu}'
\Longrightarrow
\xi' - {\rm i}\xi = \left\vert t\right\vert\,;
\qquad
{\rm u} = \Im\xi}$

$$
{{\rm d}\left({\rm e}^{-{\rm i}t}\xi\right) \over {\rm d}t}
=
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}t}\,\left\vert t\right\vert
\Longrightarrow
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}t}\xi - \left(-1 + {\rm i}\right)
=
\int_{0}^{t}{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}t'}\,\left\vert t'\right\vert\,{\rm d}t'
$$

$$
\xi
=
-{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t} + {\rm i}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}
+
\int_{0}^{t}
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\left(t - t'\right)}\,\left\vert t'\right\vert\,{\rm d}t'
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\ \\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad{\rm u}\left(t\right)
=
-\sin\left(t\right) + \cos\left(t\right)
+
\int_{0}^{t}\sin\left(t - t'\right)\left\vert t'\right\vert\,{\rm d}t'\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

${\bf ADDENDUM:}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}\sin\left(t - t'\right)\left\vert t'\right\vert\,{\rm d}t'
&=
\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}
\cos\left(t - t'\right)\left\vert t'\right\vert\,
\right\vert_{t'\ =\ 0}^{t'\ = t}
-
\int_{0}^{t}\cos\left(t - t'\right){\rm sgn}\left(t'\right),{\rm d}t'
\\[3mm]&=
\left\vert t\right\vert
+
\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}
\sin\left(t - t'\right){\rm sgn}\left(t'\right)
\right\vert_{t'\ =\ 0}^{t'\ = t}
-
\int_{0}^{t}\sin\left(t - t'\right)
\left\lbrack 2\delta\left(t'\right)\right\rbrack\,{\rm d}t'
\\[3mm]&=
\left\vert t\right\vert
-
2\sin\left(t\right)\Theta\left(t\right)
\end{align}
$$
\begin{array}{|rcl|}\hline\\ \\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad{\rm u}\left(t\right)}
& = &
\color{#ff0000}{\large-\left\lbrack 2\Theta\left(t\right) + 1\right\rbrack\sin\left(t\right) + \cos\left(t\right)
+
\left\vert t\right\vert}
\\[3mm]
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad{\rm u}'\left(t\right)}
& = &
\color{#ff0000}{\large-\left\lbrack 2\Theta\left(t\right) + 1\right\rbrack\cos\left(t\right)
-
\sin\left(t\right)
+
{\rm sgn}\left(t\right)\quad}
\\[3mm]
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad{\rm u}''\left(t\right)}
& = &
\color{#ff0000}{\large\phantom{-}\left\lbrack 2\Theta\left(t\right) + 1\right\rbrack\sin\left(t\right)
-
\cos\left(t\right)}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $t\in 0^+\cup\{0\}$ then we have $u''+u=t$. Here, you can use any appropriate methods to get the general solution for this ODE. For example by using undetermined coefficients you get: $$u(t)=C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t+t$$ Remember the  part $C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t$ is really the solution of the associated homogenous OE, $u''+u=0$. Similarly, if $t<0$, then we have $u''+u=-t$ and so we get $u(t)=C_3\sin t+C_4\cos t-t$. Therefore: $$u(t)=\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t+t & \quad t \geq 0 \\
            C_3\sin t+C_4\cos t-t & \quad t < 0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$ Now use other given conditions to find the unknown coefficients $C_i$. Note that the solution should be continuous at the origin,i.e; $\lim_{t\to 0}u(t)=u(0)$.

Comment: Ditto +1 and good night my friend! Regards

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the easiest or most systematic way to get a solution, but I had a bit of fun finding it so I'll post it anyway.

Let's look for solutions of the form $u(t) = |t|f(t)$ where $f$ is twice differentiable with $f(0)=0$. Such a function is twice differentiable everywhere, with second derivative $$ u''(t) = \operatorname{sign}(t)(2 f'(t) + tf''(t))$$ where we use the convention that the sign of 0 is 0. The differential equation is then

$$\operatorname{sign}(t)(2 f'(t) + tf''(t) + tf(t)) = \operatorname{sign}(t) t,$$ so a solution of $2 f'(t) + tf''(t) + tf(t)=t$ would suffice. The substitution $a(t) = t(f(t)-1)$ transforms this to $$a''(t) + a(t) = 0$$ with initial conditions $a(0) = 0, a'(0) = -1$; which has solution $a(t) = -\sin(t)$. Thus we have $f(t) = 1 - \operatorname{sinc}(t)$, giving a particular solution $$u(t) = |t| - \operatorname{sign}(t)\sin(t).$$

Comment: ${\large%
{\rm u}''\left(t\right)
=
\left\vert\,t\,\right\vert\,{\rm f}''\left(t\right)
+
2{\rm sgn}\left(t\right){\rm f}'\left(t\right)
+
2\delta\left(t\right){\rm f}\left(0\right)}$

Comment: @FelixMarin: which is exactly what I wrote when $f(0)=0$.